# elasticsearch - equivalent of "facets" "statistical" for aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the equivalent of "facets" "statistical" fields using aggregations?

```
"facets": {
            "text": {
                "statistical": {
                    "script": "doc['text'].values.size()"
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`stats`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-stats-aggregation.html) aggregation

```
    "aggs": {
        "text": {
            "stats": {
                "script": "doc['text'].values.size()"
            }
        }
    }
```